# Error while operator overloading (error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const char [2]’)

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef NAME_H
#define NAME_H
#include <string>                                // For string class

class Name
{
private:
 std::string first{};
 std::string second{};

public:
  Name(const std::string& name1, const std::string& name2) : first(name1), second(name2){}
  Name()=default;
  std::string get_first() const {return first;}
  std::string get_second() const { return second; }

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Name& name);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Name& name);
};

// Stream input for Name objects
inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Name& name)
{
  return in >> name.first >> name.second;
}

// Stream output for Name objects
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,  const Name& name)
{  
   //My error is here while I am adding  " " in the overload
   return out << name.first << " " << name.second;
}
```

I wanted to overload the  `<<` operator for `std::ostream` which takes in Name object as my right hand parameter.

Now when I added the " " in the overload .. it presents me with the error

The error goes like this:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const char [2]’)
   return out << name.first << " " << name.second;
                            ^
```

Comment: There's a lot of useful information in the error message.

Comment: I mean read the error message, look at your code, and figure it out. Or if you want help, post a [mcve] and explain exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: ok.. Thank you ..

Comment: Add `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: Thank you .... sometimes brain in dead :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by a simple error unrelated to the substance of the question; the question is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for uploading all the details - the question is now answerable.

The overloads you have provided cannot be reached by the compiler since `istream` and `ostream` are not complete types at the point of compilation.

You need to write

```
#include <iostream>
```

to rectify that. Sometimes compiler diagnostics are obtuse.